# How to quantile values in a pandas dataframe with individual value ranges

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe where I would like to bin the 'close' values to the according range of the day. (range = difference high and low).
I need 5 quantiles. Q1, Q2, M, Q4, Q5.
Example: low 100, high 200, close 125 = Q2

This is the df:

```
             Low    High    range   close
             amin   amax        
Date                
2019-06-20  2918.00 2946.75 115.0   2943.00
2019-06-21  2930.00 2951.50 86.0    2933.25
2019-06-24  2931.00 2944.00 52.0    2934.50
2019-06-25  2902.25 2935.25 132.0   2903.50
2019-06-26  2899.00 2921.25 89.0    2900.25
2019-06-27  2900.00 2918.00 72.0    2913.25
2019-06-28  2913.00 2937.50 98.0    2937.00
2019-07-01  2937.75 2964.00 105.0   2950.50
2019-07-02  2940.75 2962.25 86.0    2962.00
2019-07-03  2957.75 2983.75 104.0   2983.25
2019-07-04  2979.50 2986.00 26.0    2984.50
2019-07-05  2953.50 2986.25 131.0   2972.75
2019-07-08  2955.50 2971.00 62.0    2960.50
2019-07-09  2945.75 2968.50 91.0    2964.50
2019-07-10  2953.50 2989.75 145.0   2988.50
```

I'm trying to accomplish this with a loop. The array will be filled but I can't assign the values to the dataframe.

```
low = df.loc[:, ('Low', 'amin')]

def q():
    
    qarray = []
    
    for i in range(len(df)):
        
        if ((df.close[i] - low[i])/0.25)/df.range[i]*100 > 0 and ((df.close[i] - low[i])/0.25)/df.range[i]*100 <= 20:
            qarray.append('Q1')
        if ((df.close[i] - low[i])/0.25)/df.range[i]*100 > 20 and ((df.close[i] - low[i])/0.25)/df.range[i]*100 <= 40:
            qarray.append('Q2')
        if ((df.close[i] - low[i])/0.25)/df.range[i]*100 > 40 and ((df.close[i] - low[i])/0.25)/df.range[i]*100 <= 60:
            qarray.append('M')  
        if ((df.close[i] - low[i])/0.25)/df.range[i]*100 > 60 and ((df.close[i] - low[i])/0.25)/df.range[i]*100 <= 80:
            qarray.append('Q4')      
        if ((df.close[i] - low[i])/0.25)/df.range[i]*100 > 80:
            qarray.append('Q5')          
    return qarray  

df['q'] = q()
```

I get this warning message:

```
/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:23: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
```

How can I get the values from qarray to the dataframe? And, is there a more pythonian way to accomplish this task?

Comment: You might want to look at [`pd.qcut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.qcut.html)

Answer (score 2):

Stanvooz, this should should do it:

```
df["q"] = pd.qcut((df["close"] - df["low"]), q=[0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1], labels=["Q1", "Q2", "M", "Q3", "Q4"])
```

After reviewing your requirements, I think qcut will not work for your case. qcut works on the columns, what you are doing is on the row (at least that is my opinion). Below solution I think is a little more pythonic and avoids loops. It works for me on your data without error messages. I am using pandas v 1.0.1

```
_ranges = np.array([0, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100])
_map = {1: "Q1", 2: "Q2", 3: "M", 4: "Q4", 5: "Q5"} # maps label to an appropriate range

df["derive"] = ((df["close"].values - df["low"].values) / 0.25) / df["range"].values * 100 # intermediate step
df["q"] = df["derive"].apply(lambda x: _map[(x > _ranges).sum()])
df.drop("derive", axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Comment: I get the same `SettingWithCopyWarning` and no results

Comment: The solution is that I had to make a deep copy of the original dataframe wherefrom df derives. However, your solution with qcut gives me different results than my initial loop. for example, the first day will be binned with my loop to Q5, with qcut to Q4. Need to check why this is the case